# A natural deduction proof of $\neg (A \wedge B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow \neg B)$ without RAA

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am doing (for fun) the exercices of [this](https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/natural_deduction_for_propositional_logic.html) lean tutorial.

For the third exercice of section 3.6. Exercises:

"Give a natural deduction proof of  $\neg (A \wedge B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow \neg B)$."

I did the following answer:

[image]

Since I used a RAA (Reductio ad absurdum - proof by contradiction) rule, I wanted to know if it was possible doing it without this rule.

*Edit*

Thanks to the comment below of drhab, I realized that I didn't use indeed RAA ; instead it is
[image]

Comment: You did not use RAA. From hypotheses (among which $B$) you deduced that $\bot$. Then with *induction* we conclude that $B\to\bot$ (which is the same as $\neg B$) and discharge hypothese $B$.

Comment: @drhab all right, you mean that 1 RAA is false, in fact I used 1 $\neg_\mathrm{I}$ instead ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: If RAA is properly applied then the hypothese that is discharged *must* be a negation (which is not the case here).

Comment: @drhab thank you for the explanation! :) I will edit my post to show the error I made